How to get security and routing profile?
I have the following cf script creating a simple AWS Connect instance.
Resources: 
  AmazonConnectInstance:
    Type: AWS::Connect::Instance
    Properties:
      Attributes:
        InboundCalls: YES
        OutboundCalls: YES
      IdentityManagementType: CONNECT_MANAGED
      InstanceAlias: 'my-demo-1234fhy49d'

Now I'd like to create an admin user in the same cf script:
...
ConnectUserAdmin:
    Type: AWS::Connect::User
    Properties:
      IdentityInfo:
        FirstName: admin
        LastName: user
      Username: adminuser
      InstanceArn: !GetAtt AmazonConnectInstance.Arn
      RoutingProfileArn: ?????
      SecurityProfileArns: [?????]
      Password: '1234567890'

However, I can't find a way to retrieve instance's security profiles or routing profiles. For example something like this !GetAtt AmazonConnectInstance.AdminProfileArn or !GetAtt AmazonConnectInstance.DefaultRoutingProfileArn would be helpful. How could I go about it (without using a custom resource)?
Important:  I don't mean how to retrieve instance's security profiles or routing profiles using GET API or using cli aws connect.

That's a good question. I'm not sure how you can do this, but could you create new routing and security profiles and use them?

If you want to use default profiles, you need to create a custom resource to retrieve them

@ledge i got a reply from aws. They suggest to create profiles inside the cf and attach them to the user. What I don't like with this approach is that you creates duplicate profiles. Another approach is to create a custom resource and retrieve them, as Caldazar suggests. However, this approach requires Python knowledge if you want to put your code inside cf.

Yeah, @caldazar is right and is the best approach.

I believe that default profiles retain their ids during the lifetime of Amazon Connect instance.
So you only need to grab those ids once and hardcode them in your template. I assume you already hardcode the id of the instance itself, so it’s not a big difference.
Once you have access to the id within the template, you can construct the ARN manually:
arn:${Partition}:connect:${Region}:${Account}:instance/${InstanceId}/security-profile/${SecurityProfileId}

But this is specifically for creating the instance in the same cf scripf

Right. Depends on scenario, but it might worth creating the instance by hand. Otherwise it’s duplicating profiles or custom resource as discussed in the other comments.

How does your post answer the question? If you read the question carefully, then you should understand that it tries to create the user in the same cf file. At the moment you run the cf the id is not known yet. So, your answer has nothing to do with the question.
